# Can't instal Django on RedHat

Tags: python, django, proxy, redhat

I try to download Django project with pip command :

```
pip install django
```

But I get the following :

```
Downloading/unpacking django
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for django
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Of course, I tried to set env variables :

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@ip_address:port
export https_proxy=https://username:password@ip_address:port
```

But still the same error.

Furthermore, can I choose the version of Django that I install?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: I also tried :
    pip install --proxy https://username:password@ip_address:port django

Comment: the log says : 

`CertificateError: hostname 'ip_address' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', 'python.org', 'pypi.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'testpypi.python.org', 'bugs.python.org', 'wiki.python.org', 'hg.python.org', 'mail.python.org', 'packaging.python.org', 'pythonhosted.org', 'www.pythonhosted.org', 'test.pythonhosted.org', 'us.pycon.org', 'id.python.org', 'pypi.io' `

Comment: Is that literally `ip_address` or your IP address in the message and the proxy configuration?

Comment: No @KlausD. it's not literally ip_address ^^
It's 192.168.255.54 to be precise ;)

Comment: `192.168.255.54` ? Is that routable?

Comment: @RobL No this address is not routable

Answer (score 1):

> can I choose the version of Django that I install?

You can. Use `pip install Django==1.4.3` for example, to install a specific version.

Or `pip install "Django<1.9"` to get the latest stable `1.8` build.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why I cannot download Django?